# cc linker error

Tags: linux, c, cmake, gtk3, linker

I'm writing a C application based on GTKlibrary on Debian 12.
The program is build by a Makefile, generated from cmake.
The compile phase of the source files is correct but when the linker is fired I have the following error:

```
[ 3%] Linking C executable lux
cc: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
```

The CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
# Set the name and the supported language of the project
PROJECT(Lux C)
# Set the minimum version of cmake required to build this project
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

# Use the package PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

set ( ORACLE_LIBS "-locci -lclntsh")
set ( ORACLE_DIR "/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_20")

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS} ./include ./websocket/include ${ORACLE_DIR}/sdk/include/)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${ORACLE_DIR})

# Add other flags to the compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

# Add an executable compiled from *.c
ADD_EXECUTABLE( lux
    main.c log.c 
...
    dbOracle.c
)

# Link the target to the GTK+ libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lux ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} -lmysqlclient -lcurl -lpthread ${ORACLE_LIBS})

add_compile_options( -rdynamic )
```

I don't have a direct control on the flags ...

Comment: What is the command that causes the error?  Run `make VERBOSE=1` to see the actual commands executed.  Update the question with this info, don't answer in comments (would make it hard to read).